# MySql Query help required in getting result as per desire

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can someone please help me in writing the exact query, which can give me desired results for the following,

[image]

I wrote,

```
   SELECT tbl_order_detail.order_id, 
          tbl_order_detail.order_title, 
          tbl_order_detail.dealer_id
     FROM tbl_order_detail
LEFT JOIN tbl_order_lead_send_detail ON tbl_order_detail.order_id=tbl_order_lead_send_detail.order_id
    WHERE tbl_order_detail.order_status = 'Active'
```

and finding the dealer name from one php function that takes dealer_id in it and returns dealer_name (using another mysql query), and count from another mysql query

but it isn't giving my desired output. it's giving output as

[image]

But I want the above circled ones in one row only, as everything is same in them, but they are showing many times in the output (why not one).

Can someone help me in this?

Comment: Are you sure the query above gives you the output you pasted? Seems you are missing the last column in your query (count).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) order_id, you should be good to go

**Edit:**

To get the dealer name, just JOIN the dealer table and select the dealer name column.

*Untested, may contain errors*

```
SELECT
    tbl_order_detail.order_id, 
    tbl_order_detail.order_title, 
    dealer.dealer_name,
    COUNT(tbl_order_lead_send_detail.order_id) AS total_customers_count
FROM tbl_order_detail
JOIN dealers ON (tbl_order_detail.dealer_id = dealers.dealer_id)
LEFT JOIN tbl_order_lead_send_detail ON (tbl_order_detail.order_id = tbl_order_lead_send_detail.order_id)
WHERE tbl_order_detail.order_status = 'Active'
GROUP BY tbl_order_detail.order_id, tbl_order_detail.order_title, dealer.dealer_name;
```

Comment: thanks for this. Can i also get the dealer_name in my query itself? As at present I am using different query to get dealer name. Then I will have to use only one query

Comment: of course, just join the dealers table in your query, answer updated

Comment: yes, it is giving error that **#1054 - Unknown column 'dealers.dealer_id' in 'on clause'**

Answer (score 1):

To get a count, use `COUNT()`. To group your results by Order ID, use `GROUP BY tbl_order_detail.order_id` - one of the upsides of MySQL (or SQL in general) is that it's fairly close to plain English.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT OD.order_id,        
       OD.order_title, 
       OD.dealer_id,
       SD.customer_id, 
       COUNT(SD.id) AS NumCustomers
FROM      tbl_order_detail OD
LEFT JOIN tbl_order_lead_send_detail SD
      ON OD.order_id=SD.order_id
WHERE OD.order_status='Active'
GROUP BY OD.order_id,        
         OD.order_title, 
         OD.dealer_id,
         SD.customer_id
```